# Corrupt JPEG data while run program

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

[image]

I have some problem when i run my program here is my output (In this case i use logitech C310M)
But when i use my notebook webcam, it work normally

This is my code :

```
frame = vs.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)       
cvt = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = Image.fromarray(cvt)
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
lmain.imgtk = imgtk
lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
```

*i need to show video frame on Tkinter*
**My code also use openCV**

Comment: Everything stems from `frame` but you haven't showed us where you're getting that from.

Comment: @TomDalton i already edit my question , thank you

Comment: Everything stems from `vs` but you haven't showed us where you're getting that from.

Comment: @TomDalton vs = VideoStream(0) // camera position